# Pandas total sum over rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
id|number
1|1
1|0
1|1
```

I want the total sum of number in a new column like:

```
id|number|sum
1|1|2
1|0|2
1|1|2
```

I am using :

```
df['sum'] = df['number'].sum()
```

but got the output as :

```
id|number|sum
1|1|101
1|0|101
1|1|101
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem your column is not numeric, so values are concatenated.

First try convert column to `integer` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['sum'] = df['number'].astype(int).sum()
```

.. and if failed it because some non numeric value(s) use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert them to `NaN`s:

```
df['sum'] = pd.to_numeric(df['number'], errors='coerce').sum()
```